# Convert Activity To Fragment: Using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am converting an activity to a fragment. I moved the code from the onCreate to the onCreateView but now I need to return a view but I am not sure what to return. I was using a ViewPager in the activity. Any help on what I am doing wrong for the fragment is appreciated! Here is the code I have for now in the Fragment:

```
public view onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(state);

    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.reference);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.reference));

    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    views = new View[LAYOUTS.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < LAYOUTS.length; i++)
        views[i] = inflater.inflate(LAYOUTS[i], null);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.reference);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ReferenceTabAdapter());
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    container.addView(viewP);

    return viewPager;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inflate the `View` for your `Fragment` and return it.
Returned `View` will be the layout of your `Fragment`.

```
public view onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reference, null, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.reference);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ReferenceTabAdapter());
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    return view;
}
```